# Map on one-point compactification homotopic to identity

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, homotopy-theory

Let $U$ be a real normed vector space of finite dimension and $U_\infty = U\cup \{ \infty \}$ its one-point compactification. I want to construct a pointed homotopy between the following map and the identity:

$$ f: U_\infty\to U_\infty $$
given by
$$ f(u) = \frac{u}{1-|u|} \quad \text{if } |u|<1 \quad \text{and} $$
$$ f(u) = \infty \quad \text{if } |u|\geq 1. $$

Do you perhaps have some hint?

Comment: There is nothing special about the sphere with radius 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $H:U_\infty\times [0, 1]\to U_\infty$ defined using $H_t(u) := H(u, t)$ as follows should work:
$$H_t(u) =\begin{cases} \frac{u}{1-t|u|}, & t|u| < 1 \\ \infty, & t|u|\geq 1\end{cases}$$ where we interpret $|\infty | = \infty$ and $0\times \infty = \infty$. Then $H_1 = f$ and $H_0 = \text{id}_{U_{\ \infty}}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!